# JS Query variable binding

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, query, visualforce-component

Trying to transfer an apex query to Javascript. 
Wondering if binding works in the same manner?

Also is using result.length valid for the if statement?

```
var accLike = '%' + 'Construction' + '%';
var accId = '0E40040503F023FE';

result = sforce.connection.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE (Id =: accId) OR (Name LIKE :accLike)');

if(result.length > 0){
alert('result.length');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that syntax is unique to Apex. In JavaScript, you must be careful to escape any special characters manually. However, in all modern browsers (*not* IE 11), you can use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
result = sforce.connection.query(`SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = '${accId}' OR Name LIKE '${accLike}'`);
```

Note the use of backticks (`) to enclose the string, and ${variable} syntax to merge in values. Also note that strings still need to be quoted with apostrophes (" ' ").